# Conditional formula in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to set up the following formula:

I have an Overview sheet where I want to sum the fields in **Column B** in Sheet named **"Accounting",** BUT, only sum the Expenses where Column D of the same row in Sheet Accounting is **"Expenses"**

I've tried a few different formulas, and none worked. Here's the latest one I tried

=search("Expense",(Accounting!B:B)) SUM(Accounting!B:B)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMIF(Accounting!D:D,"Expenses",Accounting!B:B)
```

Comment: I litereally just came up with this too! Thanks so much Jacob :)